# Is it possible to make sure a template class size is always 2 ^ N?

Tags: c++

This is for perofrmance reasons. If I have a template class like this

```
template <typename T> struct quirky{ int a; T b; };
```

can I force c++ to pad it to make sizeof(quirky) always 2 ^ N?

so for example, if T is another int then no padding needed and size would be 8

if T is int64_t then it would pad for 4 bytes to make it 16 etc.

Comment: There is most certainly no standard way to do it. Please edit your question to specify the compiler/environment you are targeting

Comment: You can add an array of bytes, and calculate its size using `sizeof(int) + sizeof(T)` as one part of the equation. The problem is that the compiler might add padding between the member `a` and `b`, which you can't really check for. It might be possible to do something using [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) of the `b` member plus the size of `T` though, but you will still have problems with possible padding between the `b` member and the array you create.

Comment: I assume you want aligned allocation, which is quite a complex beast. For inspiration, you could look at the [Eigen matrix library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) which puts a lot of effort into aligning data for performance reasons. I guarantee you, though, that under the hood it's not pretty or straightforward…

Comment: How about using `alignas`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constructor or destructor that runs an assertion test on the size, then rely on the programmer to pad it correctly. (Which seems the C++ way IMO)

That would "make sure" that it was being used properly.

You might be able to check it with `static_assert` which would give you a compile time error if it's used wrong.

... or ...

... or do something convoluted with recursive-templates and partial-specialization to find a matching definition that's a power of 2